# jQuery dialog not working as expected

Tags: jquery

It might be a stupid problem, but I am very new to jQuery. I am trying to create a button that on-click will pop-up a login dialog. Somehow the form is shown instead of being created as a dialog. Below is my code:

```
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {   
            $('#login').dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: 'Login',
                    height: 300,
                    width: 350,
                    modal: true
            });

            $('#open').click(function() {
                $('#login_form').dialog('open');
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>        
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="login">
        <form class="caption" action="Login.php" method="post">           

        <p>E-mail: <br><input type="text" name="email" maxlength="255" /></p>
        <p>Password:</p> <br><input type="password" name="pwd" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Login" /></p>

        </form>

    </div>
    <button id="open">Click</button>
</body>
```

Any idea what I have done wrong? Thank you very much!

Comment: have you loaded the required .js files for dialoge to work

Comment: Yes he has, but I wonder if he would also need to import the jquery.js file in addition to the jquery-ui file.

Comment: Looks like you are creating a dialog out of `#login` but then you are trying to open `#login_form` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex W had it above:

From https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jqueryUI

> note: This library depends on jquery. You must also load jquery before
>   loading this module.

In addition, you're trying to `open` the `#login_form` element, rather than the `#login` element. You need to use the same jQuery set. See the modified code below.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {   
            $('#login').dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: 'Login',
                    height: 300,
                    width: 350,
                    modal: true
            });

            $('#open').click(function() {
                $('#login').dialog('open');
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>        
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="login">
        <form class="caption" action="Login.php" method="post">           

        <p>E-mail: <br><input type="text" name="email" maxlength="255" /></p>
        <p>Password:</p> <br><input type="password" name="pwd" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Login" /></p>

        </form>

    </div>
    <button id="open">Click</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked after including the jquery library!

Comment: i have included:
 `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>`
But still the box is already visible on the page!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$('#open').click(function() {
                $('#login_form').dialog('open');
                return false;
            });
```

To

```
$('#open').click(function() {
                    $('#login').dialog('open');
                    return false;
                });
```

As your dialog div's id is `login` not `login_form`.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/aZT5L/)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I was a bit rush when I posted this example of my code on and I should I apologized I made such a silly mistake that is confusing people out. I found out that even if I made it "login" it is still not working. I am suspecting I am not loading the jQuery library correctly.